# Augmented Dickey Fuller Test vs Ljung Box Test

Tags: stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

When do you use the Augmented Dickey Fuller Test and when do you use the Ljung Box test?

What are the pros and cons of using each to test for stationarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ljung Box test does not test for stationarity. It tests if the autocorrelations up to lag m are jointly equal to 0. It is always possible to have a stationary time-series that consists of significant autocorrelations. Meaning the existence of significant autocorrelations does not imply that the process is not stationary or vice versa.

Edit:

Definition of covariance stationary:

AutoCovariance Function:

$$\gamma (t,s) = Cov(Y_t, Y_s) = E((Y_t - \mu_t)(Y_s - \mu_s))$$

A stochastic process is covariance stationary if:
$$E(Y_T^2) \text{  is Finite}$$
$$E(Y_T) = \mu$$
For any $t$ and $s$:
$$\gamma (s, t) = \gamma_k \quad with \quad k = t - s$$

Meaning covariance between 2 coordinates depend on time gap between 2 points rather than specific locations of the 2 points.

Example:
$$\gamma (1, 2) = Cov(Y_1, Y_2) = Cov(Y_{99}, Y_{100}) = \gamma (99, 100)$$

Implications of covariance stationary process:
$$\gamma (t, t) = \gamma (s, s) = Var(Y_t) = \sigma^2 \quad \forall t$$

Consider AR(1) Model:
$$Y_t = c + \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$

AR(1) Properties:

Mean:
$$E(Y_t) = c + \phi_1E(Y_{t-1}) \implies \mu = c + \phi_1 \mu \implies \mu = \frac{c}{1-\phi_1}$$

Variance:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Var(Y_t) & = Var(c + \phi_1 Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t)\\
& = Var(\phi_1 Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t)\\
& \implies \sigma^2 = \phi_1^2\sigma^2 + \sigma_{\epsilon}^2\\
& \implies \sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{1-\phi^2_1}\\
& = \sigma^2_{\epsilon}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \phi_1^{2i}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

AutoCovariance:

$$Cov(Y_t, Y_{t-k}) = \frac{\phi^k_1\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{1- \phi^2_1}$$

Where AutoCorrelation:
$$p_k = \frac{\gamma_k}{\gamma_0} = \phi^k_1$$
Meaning AutoCorrelation decreases exponentially and PACF is 0 everywhere expect lag 1.

Given $|\phi_1| < 1$, mean is constant, variance is constant meaning it is finite and autocovariance only depends on $k$. Thus AR(1) process is stationary, yet autocorrelation exists and decays 0 to exponentially. Thus AR(1) is an example where process is stationary and has significant autocorrelations.

Comment: "It is always possible to have a stationary time-series that consists of significant autocorrelations" How?

Comment: @Trajan please see the edit